# Depraction warning loading file assets from src is deprecated

Tags: symfony, sass, deprecated, deprecation-warning

I have stuff like `@import '../assets/scss/WebsiteBundle/font.scss';` in `scss/WebsiteBundle/default.scss`, however, since Symfony 4.4 I get the following depracitation warning.

`Loading the file "../assets/../_photo.scss" from the global resource directory ".../src" is deprecated since Symfony 4.4 and will be removed in 5.0.`

I can't seem to find anything in the documentation about this. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using

```php
$configDirectories = [__DIR__ . '/../../templates'];
$fileLocator = new FileLocator($configDirectories);
$fileName = $fileLocator->locate($resource, null, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the **routes.yaml** file, make sure that you have all your routes with the directive **type**, this fixed this bug for me.

Example as it follows:

```
api:
    prefix: /api
    resource: '../src/Controller/Api'
    type: annotation
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However in my routes.yaml I have something like `tv:
  resource: "routes/tv_routing.yaml"
  prefix:   /` and in websitebundle_routing.yaml I have something like `tv_css:
    path:     /tv.css
    controller: 'App\Controller\StaticController::SCSSTemplate'
    defaults: { template: '../assets/scss/TvBundle/index.scss', maxAge: 1800, sharedAge: 1800, _format: css }
`